# JavaScript regular expression for the validation of comma separated string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want to validate whether the user enter data in this form **B101,202,BBB,B902,Z-102**
That is each value can be only of alphabets, digits or alphanumeric + '-'
Tried this expression but it failed for alphabets and digits only condition.
**^[A-Za-z0-9]+(,[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[A-Za-z0-9]+$**

Comment: Why not `.split(",")`?

Comment: It's for frontend validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following regex

```
^[A-Z0-9]+((,|-)[A-Z0-9]+)*[A-Z0-9]+$
```

This checks the following:

- Starts with Alphabets or Numeric
- Ends with Alphabets or Numeric

You can try it online at [Regexr.com](http://regexr.com/)

Answer (score -1):

This regex not woking with list of 1 digit numbers like 64,5,8,9

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).